# ways to cut image into 20x20 pieces with different shape of masks through cocos2dx

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

I'm working on a jigsaw game.But now I'm stucking on the problem of cutting an image.I've got an image of high resolution,I want to cut it into 20x20 pieces of different shape.I've got the mask.Now I'm trying to use ClippingNode,but the fps is not satisfying and it's too complicated to calculate the position information.I tried rendertexture,but it's worse since my pieces are too many.PLZ help me out.Here is My Demo.

```
m_obWinsize=CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getWinSize();

CCPoint obOriginPos=ccp(m_obWinsize.width/2,m_obWinsize.height/2);

CCSprite* pBg=CCSprite::create("Preview-20.png");
pBg->setScale(640.0/500);
this->addChild(pBg);

CCSprite* pSizeSp=CCSprite::create("test.jpg");
CCSize obClipSize=pSizeSp->getContentSize();
CCLog("clipsize width %f",obClipSize.width);

pBg->setPosition(ccp(obOriginPos.x,obOriginPos.y));

CCDictionary* pDic=CCDictionary::create();
char szBuf[32]={0};
sprintf(szBuf, "20.txt");
std::string strPath=CCFileUtils::sharedFileUtils()->fullPathForFilename(szBuf);
unsigned long ulSize=0;
unsigned char* pData=CCFileUtils::sharedFileUtils()->getFileData(strPath.c_str(),"rb",&ulSize);
std::string strContent;
if (isFileHasBOM(pData))
{
    strContent = (char const*) (pData + 3);
}
else
{
    strContent = (char const*) pData;
}

delete[] pData;
CC_SAFE_RELEASE_NULL(pDic);
pDic= CCJSONConverter::sharedConverter()->dictionaryFrom(strContent.c_str());
if (pDic == NULL)
{
    CCLog("JSON:%s",cJSON_GetErrorPtr());
}

int a=((CCArray*)pDic->objectForKey("tile"))->count();
CCLog("line %d",a);
float fOffset=obClipSize.width/a;
CCLog("offset %f",fOffset);

for (int i=0; i<a;i++) {
    for (int j=0; j<a; j++) {
        const char* pName=((CCString*)((CCArray*)((CCArray*)pDic->objectForKey("tile"))->objectAtIndex(i))->objectAtIndex(j))->getCString();

        CCSprite* pMask=CCSprite::create(CCString::createWithFormat("B%s.png",pName)->getCString());
        pMask->setScale(0.14f);
        pMask->setAnchorPoint(anchorWithName(pName));
        pMask->setPosition(ccp((j-(a-1)*0.5)*fOffset, ((a-1)*0.5-i)*fOffset));

        CCSprite* pSp=CCSprite::create("test.jpg");

        CCClippingNode* pClipNode=CCClippingNode::create();
        pClipNode->setPosition(obOriginPos);
        pClipNode->setStencil(pMask);
        pClipNode->addChild(pSp);
        pClipNode->setInverted(false);
        pClipNode->setAlphaThreshold(0);
        this->addChild(pClipNode);
    }
 }
```

With current code，it looks like this:
[image]

Comment: Provide *actual* code samples, alongside a *specific* problem with the code.

Comment: just need another better way to cut image into jigsaw pieces through cocos2d-x with code

Comment: Can you post a screenshot how it looks?